# Yandex map: Как получать объекты, когда двигаешь карту?

Tags: jquery, php, yandex-maps-api, javascript

Чтобы когда двигаешь карту, увеличиваешь или уменьшаешь масштаб json'ом, приходили объекты, которые входят в эти координаты. Вопрос именно в том, чтобы отправлять на определенный файл 4 координаты и вычислять, какие объекты должны быть сейчас на карте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у вас хранятся некие объекты в базе. У каждого из них есть координаты (широта и долгота).

```
// Создаем карту
var myMap = new ymaps.Map(...);
// Добавляем обработчик на событие `boundschange` карты.
myMap.events.add(function(e) {
// Запрашиваем у нашей серверной части объекты, которые помещаются
// в новые рамки, например с помощью jQuery
    $.getJSON("http://ourserver/get-map-objects.php", 
        {bounds: JSON.stringify(myMap.getBounds())
    ).done(function (data) {
// Если очень хочется, тут убираем ненужные объекты с карты (или например все)
        myMap.geoObjects.removeAll();
        $.each(data, function(ix, geo) {
            ...
// Тут помещаем объекты на карту, согласно данным из массива `data`
            myMap.geoObjects.add(...);
        }
    });
}
```

Вычислять какие объекты помещаются на карте очень можно так (например на php):

```
$bounds = json_decode($_POST['bounds']);
// Сначала нужно определить максимальные и минимальные значения каждой из 
// координат границы карты
$latMax  = max($bounds[0][0], $bounds[1][0]);
$latMin  = min($bounds[0][0], $bounds[1][0]);
$longMax = max($bounds[0][1], $bounds[1][1]);
$longMin = min($bounds[0][1], $bounds[1][1]);
// Теперь выбираем из базы или другого источника те объекты, у которых 
// коодинаты подадают в интервал между максимальным и минимальным
// значениями широты и долготы соответственно
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `geo_objects` 
      WHERE `latitude` BETWEEN :latmax AND :latmin
          AND `longitude` BETWEEN :longmax AND :longmin');
$stmt->bindParam(':latmax',  $latMax);
$stmt->bindParam(':latmin',  $latMin);
$stmt->bindParam(':longmax', $longMax);
$stmt->bindParam(':longmin', $longMin);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// Данные этих объектов возвращаем браузеру в формате JSON
header('Content-type: text/javascript');
echo(json_encode($result));
```